# ProxyPass on Amazon EC2 behind a load-balancer

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am using ProxyPass on my local machine with following directive in apache conf and it works fine:

```
ProxyPass /v2/ http://localhost:1337/
```

I need to do the same on Amazon EC2 instances which are behind a  load balancer with SSL. I tried to configure it on the instance itself but Apache gives me following error:

```
[Wed Jun 01 13:09:43.719654 2016] [proxy:warn] [pid 2664] [client 172.31.8.62:33435] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /v2/user/login. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I did some research and somewhere it said it was because of missing mod_ssl. I tried installing it and it fails because of conflicts with another version of mod_ssl. And when i see `/etc/httpd/modules` directory, it does not have mod_ssl installed.

This makes me wonder if the mod_ssl is installed on load balancer instead. I have access to load balancer as well but i have no idea how to proceed.

I do not have enough knowledge about how EC2 load balancing works so i have two questions:

- How to setup it on a machine which is not behind a load balancer and is an Amazon AMI Linux? It has `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled.
- How do i do the same for instances behind a load balancer with obviously same Linux?

Comment: What is the listener configuration on the Load Balancer? ie are you forwarding https to http? https to https? http to http? I don't think the Load Balancer is your issue, but having this information would give a clear picture of the problem. An Elastic Load Balancer doesn't care what software is on your EC2 instances. It only cares about the HTTP/TCP ports it is connecting to.